# How to merge objects and keep the interior hollow

Tags: modeling, objects

Below is an example of a rectangle and 3 cylinders overlapping each other.  Is there an automated (simple/quick) way to join them so that the interior is a hollow structure?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is the addon "BoolTool"

You can download the addon here https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Object/BoolTool

[image]

Ok the Steps the steps...

1 Created multiple objects and set them up to intersect.
2 Select all the object.
3 Hit <kbd>T</kbd> to Open the booltool panel on the tool panel in the 3d viewport.
4 There are 3 section Brush/Direct/Draw.
5 Under Direct. Select "Union"

That's all to it.

[image]

Comment: Your example is exactly what I want.  I installed BoolTool, but I'm not getting the same results.  What were the steps involved with the objects?

Comment: I updated the answer let me know if you still have problems.